# MariaDB Galera change default ports

Tags: mariadb, galera

How can I change default "MariaDB" default ports? Specifically:
4568 For Incremental State Transfer.
4444 For all other State Snapshot Transfer

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

This is controlled by `wsrep_sst_receive_address` and the "ist.recv_addr" option in `wsrep_provider_options`, as explained at the following page: https://ospi.fi/blog/mariadb-galera-firewall-configuration.html

Answer (score -1):

If you are using Docker, see if this helps:  http://withblue.ink/2016/03/09/galera-cluster-mariadb-coreos-and-docker-part-1.html